# File attach to workflow from local machine?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Alfresco community edition-5.1.x,I need to upload file during a workflow. File saved in local machine from the local machine i need attached file to workflow, Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your local machine where you're running the web browser, or locally on the server running Alfresco?

Comment: locally on the server running Alfresco

Comment: did you try to upload it using `InputStream` ?!?

Comment: Yes, I upload to alfresco repo its working is this possible without saving alfresco repository attach document to workflow

Comment: I tried using inputstream , not working

Code:
=====

  `TaskService taskService = execution.getEngineServices().getTaskService();

   //Task task = taskService.newTask();
   //taskService.saveTask(task);
   System.out.println("Step1:------>"+taskService);

   InputStream pdfStream = new FileInputStream(trainername);
   System.out.println("Step2:------>"+pdfStream);

   taskService.createAttachment("application/msword",workflowInstanceId , null, "CMISCheatSheet", "CMIS cheat sheet", pdfStream);
   System.out.println("Attached");`

Comment: @Paul do you use Primefaces ?!?

Comment: Please help with references

Comment: @Paul do you know [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/)

Comment: `TaskService taskService = execution.getEngineServices().getTaskService();

   System.out.println("workflowTaskId******"+workflowTaskId);
   TaskQuery query = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(workflowInstanceId).includeProcessVariables();
   Task theTask = query.singleResult();
    
   Map<String, Object> processVariables = theTask.getProcessVariables();  
  taskService.createAttachment("application/html",procID, null, "Score", "Score Details", trainername);`

ERROR:
----------
I am getting 

>java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: @Paul tell me if you use Primefaces if yes i can provide a download method